# JFactory::getApplication()->redirect() convert & to &amp;

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a problem in Joomla 3.6.2 when using `JFactory::getApplication()->redirect()` with route to `index.php?option=com_users&view=login` AND the return parameter.

**The code looks like this.**

```php
$uri = urlencode(base64_encode(JURI::getInstance()->toString()));
JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(
    JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return='. $uri),
    JText::_("YOU_MUST_BE_LOGGED_IN_TO_ACCESS_THIS_CONTENT", 'com_portail')
);
```

Where `$uri` would be something like this:

```
aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9wb3J0YWlsL2luZGV4LnBocD9vcHRpb249Y29tX3BvcnRhaWw=
```

With this method I get redirected to something like that:

`http://localhost/portail/index.php/component/users/?view=login&  amp;return=aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9wb3J0YWlsL2luZGV4LnBocD9vcHRpb249Y29tX3BvcnRhaWw=`

**In particular**

Note the `&amp;` that causes my page to fail to load.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use `JRoute` set the second parameter to `false` and it should work.

So your code should somewhat look like this

```
JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(
        JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return='. $uri, false), 
        JText::_("YOU_MUST_BE_LOGGED_IN_TO_ACCESS_THIS_CONTENT", 'com_portail')
        );
```

Explanaition should be found in the [JRoute-Docs](https://docs.joomla.org/API15:JRoute/) :)

regards

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$uri = urlencode(base64_encode(JURI::getInstance()->toString()));
```

TO

```
$uri = base64_encode(JURI::getInstance()->toString());
```

Dont use `urlencode`.

Comment: Hi Amit, It doesn't change anything since the part which cause me problem is outside of that variable.

index.php?option=com_users&view=login  ----> & <---- return='. $uri

This is the problem.

Comment: I believe the problem comes from the login page it self.I beleive the page is redirected twice since I'm redirecting to index.php?option=com_user and get to this page index.php/component/users...